# How to explain variation between cloudfront update times?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know cloudfront updates it's servers ~24 hours [[source]](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=37268).

My question is why does sometimes it take less than 24 hours? Like sometimes I update s3 and bam the new content is available from XXdomain.com immediately. Other times it seems like it takes the full 24 hours.

How can anyone explain the variation? Why does it seem like a non-standard amount of time to update?

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon whether the request is cached or not. If a request did not a POP (Point of Presence) it need to fetch from origin. If that is the first request, then it will need to contact the origin and serve whatever is there.

In other cases, if already cached, then it will serve whatever is cached. We don't modify contents for longer time. If you purge, usually it takes longer time like 24 hours varies based on the pop location, network availability, cacheable size for a domain, etc.,

You can use either cache headers or set you cache configuration to your desired time.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> I know cloudfront updates it's servers ~24 hours

That isn't really an accurate description of what happens.

More correctly, we can say that by default, an object cached in a CloudFront edge will be evicted after 24 hours.

There is no active update process.  The CloudFront cache is a passive, pull-through cache.  When a request arrives, it is served from cache if a cached copy is available and not stale, otherwise a request is sent to the origin server, the object is stored in the cache, and returned to the viewer.

If the cache does not contain a fresh copy of the object, it fetches it immediately from the origin upon request.  Thus, the timing of requests made by you and others will determine how frequently it *appears* that CloudFront is "updating," even though "updating" isn't really an accurate term for what is occurring.

The CloudFront cache is also not monolithic.  If you are in the Eastern U.S. and your user base is in Western Europe, you would potentially see the update sooner, because the edge that is handling your request handles less traffic and is this less likely to have a handled a recent request and have a cached copy available.

After updating your content in S3, create a CloudFront invalidation request for `/*`.  This marks everything cached previously as expired so that all subsequent requests will be sent to the origin server and all viewers will see fresh content.  Each AWS account can create 1,000 invalidation requests per month (across all distributions combined), at no cost.